# Delphi 11 "копирование" визуальных компонентов

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

Имеется самописный (в процессе) класс:

```
  TCardGridImage = class
    FCardPanel: TCardPanel;
    procedure SetCardPanel (Source: TCardPanel);
  public
    property CardPanel: TCardPanel write SetCardPanel; //FCardPanel;
  end;

procedure TCardGridImage.SetCardPanel (Source: TCardPanel);
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  OldName: string;
  as1, as2: Boolean;
begin
  as1 := Assigned(Source);
  as2 := Assigned(FCardPanel);
  OldName := Source.Name;
  Source.Name := ''; // needed to avoid Name collision
  try
    ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      ms.WriteComponent(Source);
      ms.Position := 0;
      ms.ReadComponent(FCardPanel);
    finally
      ms.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Source.Name := OldName;
  end;
end;
```

Пытаюсь присвоить в `FCardPanel` `CardPanel1`, но на строке `ms.ReadComponent(FCardPanel);` выпадает ошибка:

> raised exception class EClassNotFound with message 'Class TCardPanel not found'

Как обойти или исправить?

Comment: Что такое TCardPanel? Оно наследник TPersistent? RegisterClass для него выполнено?

Comment: ```TCardPanel = class(TCustomCardPanel)``` находится в ```Vcl.WinXPanels```

Comment: А не проще в свой собственный компонент встроить какой-нибудь метод `function Duplicate(): TCardPanel;` который будет сам создавать свою правильную копию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ОК, значит наследник TPersistent.

Класс должен быть зарегистрирован. Для компонентов в published-области формы это выполняется автоматически, если я правильно помню, а в данном случае нужно сделать то, что я написал выше - [RegisterClass](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.RegisterClass)

`Put the call to RegisterClass in a Register procedure. In Delphi, you can also put the call in the initialization section of the unit in which the class is defined.`

Unregistered classes can't be loaded or saved by the component streaming system

Comment: сделал так 
```initialization

RegisterClass(TCardPanel);```
ошибки при ```ms.ReadComponent(FCardPanel);``` больше нет, но переменная содержит ```nil```

Comment: @woojin создайте объект FCardPanel := T.Crreate(self) а после readComponent или function TStream.ReadComponent(const Instance: TComponent): TComponent; парамент const  а не var а вот result там ваш компонент

Comment: @vrgat4 попробую